# copy Charts excel to specific paragraphs word with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a word file that contains text. And I have an Excel file that has several charts. I want these charts to be copied in specific paragraphs. For example, the first chart in the fifth paragraph and the second chart in the tenth paragraph and...

I know how to copy a chart in a word file, but not in a specific paragraph.
The following code only copies the diagram into the word file, but its position cannot be adjusted (for example, in which paragraph it should be).

```
   Set chObject = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(c1) 

   chObject.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

        On Error Resume Next
        Do
            Err.Clear
            WordRange.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
            DoEvents
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop While Err.Number <> 0
        On Error GoTo 0
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look in the [Document.Paragraphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.paragraphs) collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have a word file that contains text.
And I have an Excel file that has several charts.
I want these charts to be copied in specific paragraphs.
For example, the first  chart in the fifth paragraph and the second chart in the tenth paragraph and...

Comment: @Toddleson thansk for reply.the paragraph object  don't have function.example for paste a table in specific parapraphs i use myDoc.Paragraphs(65).Range.PasteExcelTable.but for chart don't have any things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understood the answer to the problem, it is enough to use the paragraph object like the code below.
The following code copies the diagram in the fifth paragraph

```
   chObject.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

           myDoc.Paragraphs(10).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
            DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
            Placement:=wdTight, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: code should be formatted so lines should not be prepended by white spaces